# Can't push to a new project in gitlab - commit message does not follow the pattern

Tags: git, gitlab

I am struggling to push a new project to a repo on GitLab.  I have access to a repo which I don't administer but have full permissions I believe.  It is only set up to use http access.

I have a noddy little project I'm trying to create a new project in the repository to share and I just can't seem to push it.  I have tried creating the project through the browser (all seems fine, I am a member of the group and have been able to make myself master).  I have tested that I can do a push to other projects in the repo.

I then locally have followed the instructions

```
cd existing_folder
git init
git remote add origin http://git.evo.r2-org.net:9443/IMS-Prototype/versionprototype.git
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
git push -u origin master
```

but whatever I do I get (in this case I have just 2 text files in there to avoid any other possible issues!).  This message was taken after I tried making a new branch but I was getting the same message on master.

> Counting objects: 4, done. Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
>   Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done. Writing objects: 100% (4/4),
>   1.56 KiB | 1.56 MiB/s, done. Total 4 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0) remote: GitLab: Commit message does not follow the pattern 'workitem\
>   \d+' To http://pathtoremote:9443/MyProject/project.git  ! [remote
>   rejected] develop -> develop (pre-receive hook declined) error: failed
>   to push some refs to 'http://pathtoremote:9443/MyProject/project.git '

I don't think (!?) this is a permissions problem as I have permissions to clone and push back to other projects in the repo and permissions to create the project.  So I'm totally at a loss now and wondered if this meant anything to anyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as if this repository enforces rules regarding its commit messages. Your commit message must mention `workitem <number>`.

"Initial commit" does not match that pattern, hence the error message. You should maybe ask for the set of rules this repository enforces.

Comment: yes I remember now the rules were changed.  They don't seem to be enforced on existing projects so I forgotten (I guess it would add complexity as it would pull up all historic commit messages).

Comment: Just to add some additional information to this answer. The feature that is being referred to is "Push Rules" in GitLab. It can be set globally or at a project level. https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/push_rules/push_rules.html